# Proof that $G_\delta$ sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are either countable,finite, or have cardinality of the continuum.

Tags: set-theory, trees, descriptive-set-theory

Let $U$ be a $G_\delta$ set. We assume that it has empty interior and it's not countable. We have that $U=\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} A_i$ where $A_i$ are open. Wlog we can assume that $A_{i+1}\subseteq A_i$. Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable disjoint union of open intervals. Set $A_i=\bigsqcup I^i_{a}$. Consider the tree $T=\{ I^i_a:i,a\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ordered by $\supseteq$. Given any maximal branch $\{I_{a_i}^i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ it's intersection is either empty or contains a single point. We can prune $T$ without affecting $U$. There is a bijection between the elements of $U$ and the branches of the now pruned $T$ where $x\in T$ is sent to $\{I_{a_i}^i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ where for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$ $I_{a_i}^i$ is the interval of $A_i$ that contains $x$ (the inverse of this map is the intersection of a given branch). We search for an appropriate subtree.

For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an $I^i_a$ such that the number of branches that contain $I^i_a$ is uncountable since at each $i$ there can be at most a countable amount of $I^i_a$. Given a node $I^i_a$ that is contained in uncountably many branches there exist $I^j_x,I^j_y\subseteq I^i_a$ that are disjoint and are contained in uncountably many branches (as a short hand we say $I^j_x,I^j_y$ "split" the branches of $I^i_a$). We define a subtree where at the first step $J^0_0$ is any node that is contained in uncountably many branches and we set $S_0=\{J^0_0\}$. At the $n+1$-th step for all $J^n_x$ in $S^n$ we find any two $J^{n+1}_{x^\frown 0}$ $J^{n+1}_{x^\frown 1}$ that "split" the branches passing by $J^n_x$ (the bottom index will be a sequence in $\{0,1\}$). This subtree will have cardinality of the continuum.

Is this a correct proof? And would there be a more elegant way in constructing the subtree?

Edit: Looking back I realized that the "pruning" I did at the beginning was not as trivial as I thought. Not only do trivial branches have to be removed (i.e. branches with finite height) but there are also branches of $\omega$ height whose intersection is empty and at every level the node (seen as an open set) has uncountable intersection with $U$. To remove such branches we need to assure that all the child nodes closure is contained in it's predecessor. To this for each $I_a^i$ can be restricted such that it's intersection with $U$ is still uncountable. This can easily be done since the real line is separable. This assures that all branches have union that's a point.

Comment: @SamuelM.A.Luque That's only if the continuum hypothesis holds

Comment: Good point. I’ll delete.

Comment: The second sentence was presumably intended to say that $U$ has empty interior.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes it does thanks I will fix it

Comment: I know a different proof. $(1).$ Let $Y$ be a subspace of a completely metrizable space $X$. Then $Y$ is completely metrizable iff $Y$ is a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X.$ $(2).$ If $Y$ is a non-empty completely metrizable space with no isolated points then $Y$ has a subspace that's homeomorphic to the Cantor Set $C$, so $|Y|\ge |C|=2^{\aleph_0}.$ $(3).$  If $S$ is an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$ then there is  closed subset $T$ (of $\Bbb R$) such that the subspace $T\cap S$ is uncountable  and has no isolated points....Continued in next comment.

Comment: ... Continued. Now if S is an uncountable $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R$ then with $T$ as in $(3)$, the subspace $T\cap S$ is also $G_{\delta}$. Applying $(1)$ and then $(2)$ with $Y=T\cap S,$ we obtain $|S|\ge |T\cap S|\ge 2^{\aleph_0}.$

Comment: FYI, William Henry Young showed this in 1903 by proving the marginally stronger fact that every uncountable $G_{\delta}$ contains a nonempty perfect set. To be more correct historically, Young proved this for any uncountable set that can be written as the intersection of the interiors of countably many intervals, and in 1914 Hausdorff simplified the notion of a $G_{\delta}$ set to be a set that is the intersection of countably many open sets, showing (in his famous 1914 set theory and topology book) that Young's original proof (what I believe you're attempting) requires only minor adjustments.

Comment: I don't have time to deal with this now, but if no one posts a detailed answer, I'll try to come back to this at some later time and write one, perhaps with some additional historical comments, as I think it would be useful to have a  classically styled proof of it available here (meaning I'm not going to talk about trees and topology and such). I did this as part of some more extensive personal notes I wrote in Fall 1990 on various aspects of the Cantor-Bendixson theorem, but those notes are handwritten, so I'll have to "LaTeX" the portion that deals with this specific result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$ The basic idea of getting a subset of $U$ indexed by the branches of the complete binary tree of height $\omega$ can be carried out with a bit less machinery.

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for $\Bbb R$, and let $V=\bigcup\{B\in\mathscr{B}:|B\cap U|\le\omega\}$; clearly $V\cap U$ is countable, so $U_0=U\setminus V$ is uncountable. Moreover, $G\cap U_0$ is either empty or uncountable for each open $G$ in $\Bbb R$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the set of finite sequences of $0$’s and $1$’s, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\Sigma_n=\{\sigma\in\Sigma:|\sigma|=n\}$. If $\sigma\in\Sigma$ and $i\in\{0,1\}$, denote by $\sigma^{\frown}i$ the sequence obtained by appending $i$ to $\sigma$; thus, if $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$, then $\sigma^{\frown}i\in\Sigma_{n+1}$. For $\sigma,\tau\in\Sigma$ write $\sigma\prec\tau$ iff $\sigma$ is a proper initial segment of $\tau$. I’ll construct open sets $G_\sigma$ for $\sigma\in\Sigma$ in such a way that:

1. $G_\sigma\subseteq A_{|\sigma|}$ for each $\sigma\in\Sigma$,
2. $G_\sigma\cap U_0\ne\varnothing$ for each $\sigma\in\Sigma$,
3. $\{G_\sigma:\sigma\in\Sigma_n\}$ is pairwise disjoint for each $n\in\Bbb N$,
4. $\cl G_\tau\subseteq G_\sigma$ whenever $\sigma\prec\tau$, and
5. $\operatorname{diam}G_\sigma\le 2^{-n}$ whenever $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$.

Suppose that this has been done. Let $\Sigma_\omega$ be the set of infinite sequences of $0$’s and $1$’s, and note that $|\Sigma_\omega|=2^\omega$. For each $\sigma\in\Sigma_\omega$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\sigma^n\in\Sigma_n$ be the initial segment of $\sigma$ of length $n$, and let $$F_\sigma=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}G_{\sigma^n}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\cl G_{\sigma^n}\;.$$

Condition (1) ensures that $F_\sigma\subseteq U$, conditions (2), (4), and (5) and the completeness of $\Bbb R$ ensure that $F_\sigma=\{x_\sigma\}$ for some $x_\sigma\in\Bbb R$, and condition (3) ensures that if $\tau\in\Sigma_\omega$ is distinct from $\sigma$, then $F_\tau\cap F_\sigma=\varnothing$ and hence $x_\tau\ne x_\sigma$. Thus, $\{x_\sigma:\sigma\in\Sigma_\omega\}$ is a subset of $U$ of cardinality $2^\omega$.

To construct the sets $G_\sigma$, let $y_{\langle\rangle}\in U_0$ be arbitrary, let $G_{\langle\rangle}=B(y_0,1)\cap A_0$, and note that $G_{\langle\rangle}\cap U_0$ is infinite (and in fact uncountable). (Here ${\langle\rangle}$ is the sequence of length $0$.) Given $G_\sigma$ for some $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$, let $y_{\sigma^{\frown}0}$ and $y_{\sigma^{\frown}1}$ be distinct points of $G_\sigma\cap U_0$. There is a positive $r<\min\left\{2^{-(n+1)},\frac12|y_{\sigma^{\frown}0}-y_{\sigma^{\frown}1}|\right\}$ such that $\cl\big(B(y_{\sigma^{\frown}0},r)\cup B(y_{\sigma^{\frown}1},r)\big)\subseteq G_\sigma$, and we set $G_{\sigma^{\frown}i}=B(y_{\sigma^{\frown}i},r)\cap A_{n+1}$ for $i\in\{0,1\}$.

Clearly $G_{\sigma^{\frown}0}\cap G_{\sigma^{\frown}1}=\varnothing$, and for $i\in\{0,1\}$ we have $G_{\sigma^{\frown}i}\subseteq A_{|\sigma^{\frown}i|}$, $G_{\sigma^{\frown}i}\cap U_0\ne\varnothing$, $\cl G_{\sigma^{\frown}i}\subseteq G_\sigma$, and $\operatorname{diam}G_{\sigma^{\frown}i}\le 2^{-(n+1)}$, so the recursive construction goes through as desired.

Of course any complete metric space can be substituted for $\Bbb R$.